# Perform automated Scan with Arachni

Tags: security, automated-tests, gitlab, penetration-testing

I'm trying to implement an automated scan using Arachni. The goal will be to perform automated scans in GitLab repository, in which the tests are already contained. I already configured Docker image and everything, but for the moment I can only scan singles URLs, so not really "Automated". By reaching the other repository (maybe using proxy?), I will be able to reach all the tests for all the URLs present in the application.

I guess a possible solution will be to use the Proxy feature to reach the repository and perform the scan, but I'm not sure. Maybe there are also other options possible?

Does anyone have clues here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Extend paths (--scope-extend-paths) allows you to extend the scope of the scan by seeding the system with the paths contained within the given file. However, the proxy plugin is the best approach to follow.

Comment: Thank you, i guess i'll continue in that direction. Do you have any hints/suggestions about how to set or configure the proxy? Thank you very much